genomic_converter() in the Radiator package is failing because radiator_parameters() is empty, what is going on?
When I run this line of code to convert a .vcf file into a .gest file:
`genomic_converter(data = "seagrass2_noBS_thin3.recode.vcf", 
           strata = "SampleNamesStrataRegional.tsv", output = "bayescan")`



I get the following error message:
`################################################################################
######################### radiator::genomic_converter ##########################
################################################################################
Execution date@time: 20240524@1519
Folder created: 06_radiator_genomic_converter_20240524@1519
Function call and arguments stored in: radiator_genomic_converter_args_20240524@1519.tsv
Filters parameters file generated: filters_parameters_20240524@1519.tsv
✔ Reading VCF [8.8s]                                                
                                                                    
Cleaning VCF
LOCUS field empty... adding unique id instead
Filtering markers based on VCF FILTER column
Error in `radiator_parameters()`:
! parameter.obj = NULL not accepted
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Computation time, overall: 10 sec

Computation time, overall: 10 sec
######################### completed genomic_converter ##########################
✖ Importing data: vcf.file [9.6s]`

I've checked that SeqArray is uploaded correctly.
> devtools::package_info(pkgs = "SeqArray") # to verify version
 package          * version date (UTC) lib source
 askpass            1.2.0   2023-09-03 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
 BiocGenerics       0.50.0  2024-04-30 [1] Bioconductor 3.19 (R 4.4.0)
 Biostrings         2.72.0  2024-04-30 [1] Bioconductor 3.19 (R 4.4.0)
 crayon             1.5.2   2022-09-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
 curl               5.2.1   2024-03-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
 gdsfmt           * 1.40.0  2024-04-30 [1] Bioconductor 3.19 (R 4.4.0)
 GenomeInfoDb       1.40.0  2024-04-30 [1] Bioconductor 3.19 (R 4.4.0)
 GenomeInfoDbData   1.2.12  2024-05-23 [1] Bioconductor
 GenomicRanges      1.56.0  2024-05-01 [1] Bioconductor 3.19 (R 4.4.0)
 httr               1.4.7   2023-08-15 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
 IRanges            2.38.0  2024-04-30 [1] Bioconductor 3.19 (R 4.4.0)
 jsonlite           1.8.8   2023-12-04 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
 mime               0.12    2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
 openssl            2.2.0   2024-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
 R6                 2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
 S4Vectors          0.42.0  2024-04-30 [1] Bioconductor 3.19 (R 4.4.0)
 SeqArray         * 1.44.0  2024-04-30 [1] Bioconductor 3.19 (R 4.4.0)
 sys                3.4.2   2023-05-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.4.0)
 UCSC.utils         1.0.0   2024-05-01 [1] Bioconductor 3.19 (R 4.4.0)
 XVector            0.44.0  2024-04-30 [1] Bioconductor 3.19 (R 4.4.0)
 zlibbioc           1.50.0  2024-04-30 [1] Bioconductor 3.19 (R 4.4.0)


I can't find any troubleshooting help online.  Does anyone know how this error is being generated?
Thank you!
